# Puppeteer in headless false mode on ubuntu error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have this web-scraping function

```
async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            args: ['--no-sandbox', "--disabled-setupid-sandbox"]
        })
        
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://finviz.com/map.ashx');
        
        await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
    
        await page.click('.content #root > div > div:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)'); // Fullscreen
        await page.click('.content #root > div > div:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(2)'); // Share map

        await page.waitForTimeout(3000);

        const imageUrl = await page.$eval('img.w-full', el => el.src);

        console.log(imageUrl);

        await browser.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

When I try to run it on ubuntu I get an error

```
Missing X server or $DISPLAY The platform failed to initialize. 
Exiting. NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
```

If I try to run it in headless mode, I get an error

```
Error: No node found for selector: .content #root > div > div:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)
```

On my local machine the script runs fine in mode `headless : true`

How can you get out of this situation?

Comment: maybe you have two different problems: (1) servers don't have monitors so they usually don't run GUI (`X server`) so they can't display windows and you have to use `headless : true` or you may try to install fake X server like [xvfbwrapper](https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper). (2) servers may block access to external servers to stop using these servers by bots/spamers/hackers - and you may get different HTML then you expect and this may gives you second error. First you should display HTML to see if you get what you expected.

Comment: In addition, `await page.waitForTimeout(3000);` is a race condition, so if one machine is faster than another or experiences different network conditions, that sort of random sleep can easily not work. I'd use `waitForSelector` or `waitForFunction`, and only resort to `page.waitForTimeout` if you simply have no other recourse to hook onto (99% of the time you do have recourse).

Answer (score 0):

```
Missing X server or $DISPLAY The platform failed to initialize. 
Exiting. NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
```

I remember this error from a personal experience of mine. This most probably happens when the system where you are running the code is not attached to the screen.

I ran into this issue when my local script works fine and then I published the code to the development server and breaks on this error

As we can connect the server with SSH but the server don't have any screen attached. Hence this error occurs.

---

Edit 1:
The solution for this would be `headless: true`